# How to find duplicate character in a string and increase its occurence after that character in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have written a program to find the duplicate character of a string, as below:

```
string = "India";  
   
print("Duplicate characters in a given string: ");  
#Counts each character present in the string  
for i in range(0, len(string)):  
    count = 1;  
    for j in range(i+1, len(string)):  
        if(string[i] == string[j] and string[i] != ' '):  
            count = count + 1;  
            #Set string[j] to 0 to avoid printing visited character  
            string = string[:j] + '0' + string[j+1:];  
   
    #A character is considered as duplicate if count is greater than 1  
    if(count > 1 and string[i] != '0'):  
        print(string[i]);
```

But thats not it I just want to increase the duplicate character by putting one extra occurence of that character.

For Example:

```
input : "India"(Here Duplicate Character is 'i')
output : "IIndiia"(Increase one occurrence of the duplicate character)
```

Can any one help me in solving this?

Comment: It seems more like java coding style.. not python

Comment: No, its in python, And I have also followed PEP8 rules.

Comment: @NiladryKar It may be Python, but the spurious semi-colons should still be removed :)

Comment: You realize that `"i"` and `"I"` are *different* characters. Nowhere in your question or your code do you mention anything about *case*, so how do you expect the code to detect duplicates in the sample string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect all counts in one go, and do so case-insensitively:

```
from collections import Counter

string = "India"
c = Counter(string.lower())

"".join(x * (1 + (c[x.lower()] > 1)) for x in string)
'IIndiia'
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use standard python string methods:

```
line = "some string"
result = ""
for letter in line:
    result = result + letter
    if line.upper().count(letter.upper()) > 1:
        result = result + letter
```